# Why does old code initialize SSL before URL.openConnection()?

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2

I am maintaining some old Java code (written with JDK 1.7 in mind) which contains this snippet:

```
static {
    SSL_PKG = "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol";
    SSL_PROVIDER = "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider";
}

private void initHttps() {
    String str = System.getProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs");

    if (str == null || str.indexOf(SSL_PKG) < 0) {
        if (str == null) {
            str = SSL_PKG;
        } else {
            str = str + "|" + SSL_PKG;
        } 
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", str);

        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(SSL_PROVIDER);
            Provider provider = (Provider)clazz.newInstance();
            Security.addProvider(provider);
        } catch (Exception exception) {}
    } 
}
```

The private method `initHttps()` is called before connecting to an https endpoint using `URL.openConnection()`. Can someone explain what this does? Is it necessary to initialize HTTPS in this way for later JDK versions? What happens if `URL.openConnection()` is called without any initialization?

Comment: Perhaps you should try it.

Comment: Forget 1.7 (publicly just 7), this wasn't even needed in **1.5**; I _think_ it was in 1.4, two decades ago. `URL.openConnection()` on https: uses the factory defined by `HttpsURLConnection` either per-instance or globally, and if not set by code this uses the SunJSSE implementation and default truststore (and no keystore). Note in 7 a default SSL client offers only (SSLv3 if below 7u76 and) TLSv1.0, and nowadays almost all servers don't accept that/those; 7 _implements_ 1.1 and 1.2, at least the latter of which is still acceptable, but you must enable them.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085 and rzwitserloot for your replies. I removed the code, as you suggested. It has been 2 months since the code went into production, and customers have not reported any problem. So, I guess it's all good!